# Program consisting of multiple executable files

Tags: language-agnostic

If you're familiar with the internals of git (even a little bit), you may know that the `git` command is just the frontend to many other executables (as in, git is comprised of **multiple** executables, instead of a single binary file.

How does this "multiple-executable" architecture work, and is there any example of a program (ideally in C/C++) of a program that consists of multiple executables?

As you can see, this directory contains a lot of `git-*` executables.
[image: Talking about all these git-* executables.]

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it could be to execute shell commands, such as Python `os.system` or `system()` in C/C++.

Say we have an app named `app`, consisting of three executables `app-cmd1`, `app-cmd2`, and `app` itself.

I could program `app` in a way that it would call `app-cmd1` if I ran `app cmd1`, same with `app-cmd2` which could be called with `app cmd2`. Note the lack of the `-` hyphen.